# Pass environment to module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm very much used Lua where you are able to do this, so please excuse me if this is not possible.

Lets say on client.js I have 2 variables, both of these requiring modules

```
var EmbedManager = require('Embed');
var client       = require('Client');

new EmbedManager()
  .init()
  .output()
```

from the module 'Embed' I need to be able to access the variable 'client' without passing anything as an argument.

For the purpose of example, the files are stored like so;

```
Client.js
Embed.js
```

Comment: Short version. You can't. What's wrong with an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access a variable from another module, you'd need to include the variable in your `module.exports`, and then require that module.

So, in `Client.js`, you'll need to add a line like:

```
// This creates a new exported variable on Client
module.exports.client = client
```

And then in `Embed.js`, you'll need to:

```
// When you import `Client.js`, you're getting whatever
// it `module.exports`
var Client = require("./Client.js")
// So now we can access the `client` variable of the `Client` module
var client = Client.client
```

It's surprisingly tricky to find good documentation for the CommonJS module format, but this article isn't too bad: [An Introduction to CommonJS](http://eng.wealthfront.com/2015/06/16/an-introduction-to-commonjs/).

Answer (score 1):

In node js the first thing you would think about if you don't want to pass argument is to just require `Client` in your `embed.js` file, but this will cause a cyclic dependency issue. As `client.js` include `embed.js` and vise versa.

Usually the best way to deal with that is to restructure your modules in a way where you end with one file that use both `client.js` and `embed.js` so you might need to create `<thirdFileName>.js` and then require both `client.js` and `embed.js` and add your logic in that file

`thirdFile.js`

```
var EmbedManager = require('Embed');
var client       = require('Client');

new EmbedManager().init().output()

new Client().init()

//rest of logic here!
```

So either use arguments, or structure your code to use both modules in one file